# Oracle - how to convert string to row pair with out using WITH clause

Tags: regex, oracle

In one of the column I have role and organization position
Example postion is 1 and organization is 310492 ...

```
1|310492|1|12319|1|562548|1|5202558
```

I need to convert this string to multiple rows

```
1,310492
1,12319
1,562548
1,5202558
```

I can not use WITH clause as I need to have is as correlated subquery

```
SELECT   EXTRACT (VALUE (d), '//row/text()').getstringval () 
  FROM (SELECT XMLTYPE (   '<rows><row>' || REPLACE (USERPROF.FIELD1, '|', '</row><row>') || '</row></rows>'  ) AS xmlval FROM USERPROF WHERE FIELD1 IS NOT NULL   ) x, TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x.xmlval, '/rows/row'))) d
```

however this is converting entire string to multiple rows.

I tried playing with regexp and connect which is not helping me but fetching content of entire table by ignore where condition.

```
 select regexp_substr(FIELD1,'[^|]+', 1, LEVEL) from USERPROF WHERE USERS_ID = 23502
   connect by regexp_substr(FIELD1, '[^|]+', 1, level ) is not null;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A common table expression ("`with`" clause) *can* be used as a co-related subquery: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/0c690/2

Comment: In the xml approach, instead of `REPLACE(USERPROF.FIELD1, '|', '</row><row>')` try `regexp_replace(USERPROF.FIELD1, '(\d\|\d+)\|', '\1</row><row>')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL below:

```
with data as
(select '1|310492|1|12319|1|562548|1|5202558' as x from dual)
select fin from(
    select          1+level-1 as occurrence
                    , instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1) as pos
                    , nvl(lead(instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1),1) over (order by 1+level-1)
                        , length(x))
                        as xxxx
                    ,   case when 
                                    nvl(lead(instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1),1) over (order by 1+level-1)
                                        , length(x)) = length(x)
                                        then instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1)
                                        else
                        nvl(lag(instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1),1) over (order by 1+level-1),1) end as yyyy
                    , substr(x
                              ,case when 
                                    nvl(lead(instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1),1) over (order by 1+level-1)
                                        , length(x)) = length(x)
                                        then instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1)
                                        else
                        nvl(lag(instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1),1) over (order by 1+level-1),1) end
                              ,nvl(lead(instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1),1) over (order by 1+level-1)
                        , length(x))
                                - case when 
                                    nvl(lead(instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1),1) over (order by 1+level-1)
                                        , length(x)) = length(x)
                                        then instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1)
                                        else
                        nvl(lag(instr(x,'|',1,1+level-1),1) over (order by 1+level-1),1) end
                              ) as fin
                      , length(x) as lastrw
    from data
    connect by level <= length(x) - length(replace(x, '|')) - 1
    order by 1) x
where mod(occurrence,2) = 1 or xxxx = lastrw
```

Results in:

```
FIN
1|310492
|1|12319
|1|562548
|1|520255
```

Note that I'm just using the with clause to use the data you gave as an example.